# Syntax/formatting when nesting objective-c blocks

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsblockoperation

I'm nesting blocks, and it looks UGGGGLY. Is there a way to write this less ugly? Mostly looking for syntax suggestions, rather than structural, but I'll accept either.

My block factory method,

```
-(NSImage *(^)(CGFloat size, BOOL preview))resizeBlock {

return (NSImage *(^)(CGFloat size, BOOL preview))[[^(CGFloat size, BOOL preview){
        // image-resizing code
        return [[[NSImage alloc] init] autorelease];
    } copy] autorelease];

}
```

Which is called from a number of functions similar to this,

```
-(void)queueResize:(CGFloat)targetSize toView:(NSImageView *)targetView {
    NSImage*(^sizeBlock)(CGFloat,BOOL) = [self resizeBlock];
    NSBlockOperation *bo = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
        NSImage *previewImage = (NSImage*)sizeBlock(targetSize,YES);
        targetView.image = previewImage;
    }];
    [queue addOperation:bo];
}
```

queue is an NSOperationQueue object. It won't compile without all the (ugly ugly) casting. Amidoinitrite?

Edit:
As per Dave DeLong's answer, and http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/, I changed the line

```
targetView.image = previewImage;
```

to be,

```
[targetView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:previewImage waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: @Jesse, man don't playa hate, appreciate.

Comment: Haha its my 'main' language, so i wasn't hating just joking around. As far as the code...it looks about as pretty as it can using blocks i believe, but not really an expert.

Comment: Is `[self resizeBlock]` called anywhere else in your program, or just in the `queueResize:toView:` method?

Comment: @Jesse you'd have the same problem in C if you were using function pointers.

Comment: @itai ferber, yeah i have a handful of methods that do different things with the resized image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `typedef`:

```
typedef NSImage *(^KWResizerBlock)(CGFloat size, BOOL preview);
```

This makes your code become:

```
- (KWResizerBlock) resizeBlock {
  KWResizerBlock block = ^(CGFloat size, BOOL preview){
    // image-resizing code
    return [[[NSImage alloc] init] autorelease];
  };
  return [[block copy] autorelease];
}

-(void)queueResize:(CGFloat)targetSize toView:(NSImageView *)targetView {
  KWResizerBlock sizeBlock = [self resizeBlock];
  NSBlockOperation *bo = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSImage *previewImage = sizeBlock(targetSize, YES);
    //do something with previewImage
  }];
  [queue addOperation:bo];
}
```

One word of caution:

Your `NSBlockOperation` is going to be executing on a thread that's not the main thread, and so it is unsafe to manipulate any UI element from within that context.  If you need to put the `previewImage` onto the UI, then you should `dispatch_async()` back to the main thread (or something functionally equivalent).

It may work right now, but it is **strongly** discourage and can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: This is great, and you can even shorten the first method up by copying and releasing an anonymous block; you don't even have to declare it first.

Comment: @itaiferber yeah, but I find it to be much easier on the eyes to not invoke methods on a block as part of their creation.  Just my preference.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. Thanks so much!